# How to add something after every number in a string in PYTHON?

Tags: python, string

Say, I want to change the string 'A = (x+**2.**)*(y+**3.**)-**1**'

to

'A = (x+**2.0e0**)*(y+**3.0e0**)-**1.0e0**'.

Every number like 2. or just 2 should be changed. How to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define `"number"`. What should be the result of replacing this string for example: `1.2.3 4.5 6,7.8,9.a.6.c.0e891.0`?

Comment: format of "number" will either be 2. or 2      No 1.2.3 stuff will exist in the string. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the comment you wrote, this kind of regular expression should work:

```
import re

str = 'A = (x+2.)*(y+3.)-1'
print re.sub(r'(\d+)\.?',r'\1.0e0',str)
```

Output:

```
A = (x+2.0e0)*(y+3.0e0)-1.0e0
```

**Explanation of regexp:**

- `(...)` - means capturing group, what you need to **capture** to reuse during replacement
- `\d` - means any number, equivalent to [0-9]
- `+` - means 1 or more occurance, equivalent to `{1,}`
- `\.?` - means that we want either 0 or 1 `dot`. `?` is equivalent to `{0,1}`

In replacement:

- `\1` - means that we want to take first **captured** group and insert it here

Comment: Added some explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to look at the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). Specifically, `re.sub()`. Read through the entire documentation for that function. It can do some rather powerful things. Either that or something like a `for match in re.findall()` construct.

Comment: Thanks.I've tried that but I don't know how to pass the number to the substituted output. Like, I'm able to translate 'A = x*2 + y+3' into 'A = x*something + y+something' but I'm not able to make it know the 2 and 3...